# How do I secure my C# app's updates?

Tags: c#, security, https, updates

I'm planning to have my C# app update automatically by comparing version numbers and downloading a package with the new files from my server over HTTPS.

Is this enough? Can I somehow validate that the file I downloaded is indeed the one I wanted? Is there something in .NET 4.5.1 that resembles iOS's App Transport Security?

Comment: Why not write an updater app that downloads the latest files from pre defined url ?

Comment: ...but that's exactly what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not exactly what you, but you can use the [ClickOnce installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which is available in Visual Studio. It will check for updates automatically and hashes the files downloaded and verifies the checksum with the one on the server to ensure it is the correct one.

- To enable automatic updates go to the Properties of the projects, then go to the Publish tab, click Updates, and then check **The application should check for updates**
- To create the installer go to the build menu and click **Publish application_name**

Comment: Wouldn't I need a code signing certificate for that?

Comment: Signing is optional, but is recommended. If you go to the project properties > Signing, the option to sign is there.